# How do I shutdown my program with a JButton ActionListener?

Tags: java, events, button, shutdown, actionlistener

I have a button, and a buttonhandler(ActionEvent) for it.
Now, I want to make it so that, when you click the button, your program shuts down. 
How would I go about doing this?
My buttonhandler code:

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e){

    }
}
```

So I basicly need to shutdown the whole JFrame.

Comment: My ButtonHandler is in another class then the mainFrame is, how would I do it then?

Comment: pass a reference to the class that implements ActionListener. See @Chris's answer, it summarizes what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are shutting down the entire program, you can use `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your ButtonHandler would have a reference to the JFrame it's a member of and call JFrame.dispose();

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    final JFrame parent; 
    public ButtonHandler(JFrame p) { parent = p; }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e){
        parent.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the answer under me answered it more easily, and a quick way.